# subset data based on a date time difference or window

Tags: r, datetime, diff, subset

I have location data that has a date time stamp.  These locations were supposed to be collected at regular time intervals, however it doesn't always happen that way.  I need to extract those locations that are within a time window.  So, for instance, locations that are 12 hours apart.  If I start with the Datetime from location 1, find the next location that is 12 hours later in time. If there isn't one exactly 12 hours, then the next closest to that new specified time.  Then take that new location and find the next within 12h from that time.  And I have to do this for each unique ID.

```
COLLAR_ID                    dt
2159    2006-01-27 13:02:55
2159    2006-01-27 14:01:12
2159    2006-01-27 15:01:04
2159    2006-01-27 16:01:09
```

is what the data looks like and here's a short subset of the data that you can cut and paste.  Note it is all the same ID, I have 5 different IDs with different start date/times

```
structure(list(COLLAR_ID = c(2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 
2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 
2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 2159L, 2159L), dt = structure(c(1138366975, 
1138370472, 1138374064, 1138377669, 1138381264, 1138384873, 1138388503, 
1138399312, 1138402842, 1138406507, 1138413700, 1138417261, 1138420848, 
1138424444, 1138428071, 1138431695, 1138435287, 1138438938, 1138442428, 
1138446098), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), .Names = c("COLLAR_ID", 
"dt"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 20L))
```

So I think that from the example data, If my start date is 2006-01-27 at 00:00:00 time, then the next location it should record is at 12:00:00 - however this location does not exist so it should record 13:02:55.  But even this is "out side" a strict 1 hour buffered window by 2 minutes.

I had thought of converting the date time to a Julian decimal number to make it easier to work with, but I don't know how to do that.  Rounding the date/time to just hours would be OK, except sometimes there are 2 or 3 locations taken within a 1 hour time interval, so then I somehow need to select among those 1 location that is "closest in time" to the original start.

So to add new detail likely making things more confusing - some data initially was collected at 1 hour intervals, then after 3 weeks it switched to 12 hours.  But, I do not know the programmed time each one was supposed to switch.  Others started at 12 hours with a start of 00:00:00, but switched to 1 hour intervals and then after several days switched to 12 hour - but again without knowing which time of day it made the switch.  so, it could have switched to the 12 hour starting at 2pm.

I was trying to look at [this stack overflow conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092081/r-subset-a-data-frame-based-on-times-that-are-within-a-certain-number-of-minute) but can't see how that would work.  So, this is my attempt below, which I have updated now from original posting of question.  It DOES NOT WORK.  I am still working on it....It still seems rather clunky of code.

```
 test2 = test2[order(test2$COLLAR_ID,test2$dt),]
test2$dt <- as.POSIXct(strptime((test2$dt), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz="GMT")
MinInterval = 12 #minimum time interval (in hours) between consecutive locations
row = 0           # Keeps track of row within alldata
Endtest2 = 2                  #keeps track of row within individual within all data
SubData1 = test2[1,]
IDNames = levels(as.factor(test2$COLLAR_ID))
test22 = data.frame()

for (n in 1:length(IDNames)){
  IndivData = test2[test2$COLLAR_ID==IDNames[n],]
  row = row+1               #Continues to track next row between individuals
  Endtest2 = 2               #restarts counting the rows for NEXT individual
  SubData1[row,]=IndivData[1,]

  while (Endtest2<nrow(IndivData) ){
    timediff = difftime(IndivData$dt[Endtest2],SubData1$dt[row],units = "hours")

    if (timediff>MinInterval){          #If time difference is greater than 47 hours then do
      row = row+1
      SubData1=rbind(SubData1,IndivData[Endtest2,])
      Endtest2 = Endtest2+1                
    } else{
      Endtest2 = Endtest2+1
    }
  } #end while loop

} #end loop through individuals
test22 =SubData1
} #end conditional to subset data
```

I apologize and am embarrassed to say, that I completely forgot I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448068/irregular-time-series-data-can-i-make-it-regular-in-r?rq=1) on this (using similar code) long back, but never got any solutions.  I had abandoned the entire endeavor and yet now am revisiting it with new data (much more chaotic data) and a new need.  The script does not filter out the right data.

Comment: did the answer work for you?  It seemed it did.  If so, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3):

Using the nifty `roll` feature from `data.table`, you can get the closest time stamp to midnight/noon:

```
# Make data (hourly time stamps +- random noise with 30 min standard dev)

len <- 30  # Days
stamps <- seq(as.POSIXct("2013-12-01"), by="-1 hour", length.out=len*12) + rnorm(len*12, 0, 1800)
stamps.target <- seq(as.POSIXct("2013-12-01"), by="-12 hour", length.out=len)

# Use data table to join stamps.target (midnight/noon) to stamps (hourly w/ noise)

library(data.table)
dt.data <- data.table(stamps, closest.match=stamps, key="stamps")
dt.target <- data.table(stamps.target)
dt.data[dt.target, roll="nearest"]

#                    stamps       closest.match
#    1: 2013-12-01 00:00:00 2013-12-01 00:24:20
#    2: 2013-11-30 12:00:00 2013-11-30 11:57:10
#    3: 2013-11-30 00:00:00 2013-11-29 23:41:29
#    4: 2013-11-29 12:00:00 2013-11-29 11:39:32
#    5: 2013-11-29 00:00:00 2013-11-28 23:31:32
#   ....
```

---

EDIT: solution with multiple collars

While the following is a fair bit of code, most of it is generating the data.  The actual work is really just the last three lines:

```
# Make data (hourly time stamps +- random noise with 30 min standard dev)

len <- 30  # number of 12 hour intervals
pets <- c("fido", "rosie", "felix")
start.date <- as.POSIXct("2013-12-01")

# Create random roughly 1 hour apart time stamps for
# our pets and store in data table.  

library(data.table)
stamps.data <- 
  do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
      pets,
      function(x) {
        data.table(
          pet=rep(x, len * 12), 
          stamp.join=seq(
            start.date, 
            by="-1 hour", 
            length.out=len*12
          ) + rnorm(len*12, 0, 1800)
  ) } ) )
# The above looks complicated, but just creates our
# data, a 3 column data table with roughly hourly time
# stamps for each pet: 
#         pet          stamp.join
#    1: rosie 2013-11-16 01:16:32
#    2:  fido 2013-11-16 01:24:28
#    3: felix 2013-11-16 01:24:40
#    4:  fido 2013-11-16 01:50:54
#    5: rosie 2013-11-16 02:33:49
#   ---                          
# 1076: felix 2013-11-30 22:50:22
# 1077: rosie 2013-11-30 23:10:52
# 1078: felix 2013-11-30 23:52:32
# 1079:  fido 2013-12-01 00:24:01
# 1080: rosie 2013-12-01 00:34:36   

# Now add a copy of stamp.join to the data table; necessary
# because we will lose the stamp.join column in the join

stamps.data[, closest.match:=stamp.join]

# Now, for each pet, create a data.table with the target
# times (CJ does a cartesian join of our pets and our target
# times vectors and returns a data table, this is necessary
# because we are doing a rolling join, if it was an exact
# join we wouldn't need to CJ with pets, could just use
# target stamps)

stamps.target <- CJ(pets, seq(as.POSIXct("2013-12-01"), by="-12 hour", length.out=len))
setkey(stamps.data, pet, stamp.join)  # join on pet and stamp.join

# Use data table to join stamps.target (midnight/noon) to stamps (hourly w/ noise)

stamps.data[stamps.target, roll="nearest"][order(stamp.join)]

#       pet          stamp.join       closest.match
#  1: felix 2013-11-16 12:00:00 2013-11-16 12:03:31
#  2:  fido 2013-11-16 12:00:00 2013-11-16 12:20:55
#  3: rosie 2013-11-16 12:00:00 2013-11-16 11:36:37
#  4: felix 2013-11-17 00:00:00 2013-11-17 00:01:48
#  5:  fido 2013-11-17 00:00:00 2013-11-17 00:12:11
#  6: rosie 2013-11-17 00:00:00 2013-11-16 23:47:56
#  ----
```

Comment: very nice feature **roll**, you just streamlined half my codes, cheers

Comment: So Ive been trying to get this to work, but the problem is, In my example I used 00:00: as the original "target" as if I actually knew the target time.  The target time is different for each individual and changes.  I will try to explain in the example.

Comment: @BrodieG can you show how I can incorporate unique individuals into your code?  I think your code works, but it doesn't account for the multiple individuals that have the same date - it still takes just the closest. I tried: `dt.test<-dt.data[dt.target, roll="nearest", by = COLLAR_ID]` but this will not work because I set key to the date_time (dt) variable.

Comment: @BrodieG One other thing, I can't quite understand why I need the `closest.match=stamps` column.  How is that used?  It seems to just copy the data.

Comment: @Kerry, see the updated answer.  Your `by` modification doesn't work because `by` just affects the aggregation of your result, not the joining between the tables.  Also, you need to add the closest.match column because the original stamps column gets lost in the join.  Usually that's not a problem because you still have the outer table column and in a join it is typically the same as the column you just lost, but because we use a rolling join they are actually not the same, so you need an extra copy so you can see after the join.

Answer (score 0):

using your provided data set (I created an object named *temp* from your structure), this is what I came up with. This code will create 12 hours stamps for each observation, and in the end pick the first observation in each 12 hours window by dropping all observations after the first one made.

```
# create an xts object, I just find them easier to work with
xts_object<-xts(temp$COLLAR_ID, order.by=temp$dt)

# extract time and floor to 12 hours
time<-temp$dt
time_numeric<-as.numeric(time)
# 43200 is the number of seconds in 12 hours
floored_time<-c(floor(time_numeric/43200)*43200)
floored_time<-as.POSIXct(floored_time, origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00")

# create a new xts object with the floored index
floored_xts_object<-xts(xts_object, order.by=floored_time)

# drop double time stamps, leaving just the first observation in those 12 hours
unique_xts_object<-make.index.unique(floored_xts_object, drop=T)
```

feel free to try *ceiling* or *round* instead. Hope this helps.

I've added some code to pick the time stamp with the smallest time difference to the unique 12 hours, keeping the original time stamp, returning a POSIXct object with those time stamps with the smallest time difference to your 12 hours.

```
# make floored times unique
unique_time<-unique(floored_time)

# use difftime in lapply to get time differences for each unique time to all time stamps
time_diffrences<-lapply(unique_time, difftime, time)
small<-lapply(time_diffrences, abs)
small<-as.data.frame(small)
names(small)<-NULL

# get back into an xts object of time differences
small<-xts(small, order.by=time)
# using apply on the xts object, find the minimum for each unique time, selecting with
# with which, and just extracting the index instead of the entire array
smallest<-index(small[arrayInd(which(as.array(small)%in% apply(small, 2, min), arr.ind=T), dim(small))[,1]])
```

this the allows you to pick those time stamps from your xts data

```
# select from your original xts_object those line
selected<-xts_object[smallest]
```

Best,
Ben